# Running Visual Studio 2005 Express on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have to use Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7. So I started downloading the Express Edition and succesfully installed SP 1. When I start Visual Studio I get an error message saying that the 2005 SP1 Update for Windows Vista is needed.

But the Vista Service Pack I get here:

https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=7524

Does not seem to work for the Express version, error message says that the program is missing. So my question is:

(1) Is there a Vista Service Pack for the Visual Studio 2005 Express edition? And where to find it.

(2) If not, where can I download a registration free version of Visual Studio 2005, in order to use the regular sp1 and vista sp?

Please save me hours of searching, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, it seems to be a silly issue:

I used the wrong patch. The patch for the german version (VS80sp1-KB932234-X86-DEU.exe) did not work, but the english one (VS80sp1-KB932232-X86-ENU.exe) did.

So I recommend trying the available patches if it doesn't work, just like the installation of SP 1, which you have to do before installing the windows vista patch.

Thanks!